# select multiple rows in one result row

Tags: mysql

In one of my tables i store my advertisement data, thats one row per advertisement.
I also store some dates in an other table, but that's one row per date because i don't know howmany dates a specific advertisement gets.
I want to select al the dates (where ID adventisement = 1) in the same query as the data selection, seperated bij a komma. Only problem is that i get as many rows as there are dates, i only want one row with al the data…..

```
Table 1 (Advertisements)
ID_adv         data 1             data2
1              name1              picture1
2              name2              picture2  
3              name3              picture3
4              name4              picture4

Table 2 (Dates)
ID  ID_adv      date
1     2     1-1-2012
2     2     2-1-2012
3     3     1-1-2012
4     3     2-1-2012
5     3     3-1-2012
6     3     4-1-2012
```

Outcome query `(Select ID_adv, data1, data2, dates WHERE ID_adv = 3)`

```
3,name3,picture3,"1-1-2012,2-1-2012,3-1-2012,4-1-2012"
```

The dates column can be one string with al the dates seperated by a comma….

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY` to get the results you desire:

```
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.date) AS dates
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t2.ID_adv = t1.ID_adv
GROUP BY t1.ID_adv
```

This returns all the dates for each advertisement, concatenated by commas. Where there are no dates in Table2 for a particular advertisment, you'll get NULL for the dates column.

To target a particular advertisement, simply add the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.date) AS dates
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t2.ID_adv = t1.ID_adv
WHERE t1.ID_adv = 3
GROUP BY t1.ID_adv
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn rows into a column with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function