# alternative to join 3 tables without repeticions

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in mysql, table A, B and C.
C has a relationship with B (b_id) and B has a relationship with A (a_id).

that means A has many B, and B has many C. To select all, I have this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.text, b.ptext, c.ctext
FROM tableA as a
JOIN 
  tableB as b 
ON 
  (b.p_id = a.id)
JOIN 
  tableC as c 
ON 
  (c.p_pid = b.pid)
WHERE a.id = 1
```

which returns this:

```
| ID |  NAME |         TEXT |  BTEXT |  CTEXT |
|----|-------|--------------|--------|--------|
|  1 | page1 | futkdvthsa_1 | post_1 | thing1 |
|  1 | page1 | futkdvthsa_1 | post_2 | thing2 |
|  1 | page1 | futkdvthsa_1 | post_2 | thing3 |
```

is there any chance of getting something like this:

```
id |  name |         text | posts
 1 | page1 | futkdvthsa_1 | posts (post_1 = ( thing1 ), post_2 = ( thing2, thing3 ) )
```

Sigle queries for each table or would need to do in a php way?

P.S. this would be for a wordpress plugin with custom tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select multiple rows in one result row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788670/select-multiple-rows-in-one-result-row)

Comment: The problem is that in "C" has some serialized columns.  
will not cause problems with the separator GROUP_CONCAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simplest way to do this is by doing it with php.
You would have to use a stored procedure to concatenate your fields with sql.