# Return the results of sql in only one row

Tags: mysql

I am getting all the possible members in `users` table using this query:

```
      SELECT u.id as id , 
             u.name as name, 
             u.age as age 
      FROM users u
```

Obviously the results is:

```
 id     name   age  
-----------------------
 21     name1   age1
 22     name2   age2
 23     name3   age3
 24     name4   age4
```

What I want is to get the final result below:

```
 id_1     name_1   age_1    id_2     name_2   age_2    id_3    name_3   age_3    id_4     name_4   age_4 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   21      name1    age1     22      name2    age2      23      name3    age3      24      name4    age4
```

As you can see in the final result I want to return it in one row. Is that possible? If its possible, Can I asked you any suggestion on how to achieve it? Any answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788670/select-multiple-rows-in-one-result-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement doesn't look practical in data manipulation. But if it's what you're looking for as a mean for formatting...

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 21, id, NULL)) AS id_1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 21, name, NULL)) AS name_1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 21, age, NULL)) AS age_1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 22, id, NULL)) AS id_2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 22, name, NULL)) AS name_2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 22, age, NULL)) AS age_2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 23, id, NULL)) AS id_3,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 23, name, NULL)) AS name_3,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 23, age, NULL)) AS age_3,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 24, id, NULL)) AS id_4,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 24, name, NULL)) AS name_4,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(id = 214, age, NULL)) AS age_5
FROM users
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: @Thanks for giving me the idea